# 404 error when connecting to IP address but not in domain name

Tags: node.js, nginx

I ran a website with Nginx and NodeJS on Lightsail.

When I go to my mywebsite.com, my website is accessible and is secure. However, when I try to enter the public IP for that website, Nginx returns a 404 error page. The website is certified by LetsEncrypt.

I do manage to access the IP address on the browser by adding http:// before the IP address. However, when I normally go to my IP address, Nginx returns a 404 error. Why is this so?

I'm fine with the IP being not accessible. But my CDN is not working because of it. I think it needs to be accessible and not return a 404 page?

Why do I go about diagnosing and solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to show us your Nginx config.  Also, if you're using HTTPS, you must use the hostname or the browser will get certificate errors.

Answer (score 2):

The `Host:` header identifies the hostname/domain-name used by the browser to access a website when the webserver is serving multiple websites on the same TCP binding (IP address + port number + protocol). The webserver then uses that to determine what content to serve.

Web-browsers generate the `Host:` header from the URI in the address bar.

When you access `http://1.2.3.4/foobar` your browser sends this request:

```
GET /foobar
Host: 1.2.3.4
```

When you access `http://example.com/foobar` your browser sends this request:

```
GET /foobar
Host: example.com
```

When you access `http://www.example.com/foobar` your browser sends this request:

```
GET /foobar
Host: www.example.com
```

When you access `https://example.com/foobar` (or `https://www.example.com/foobar`) as opposed to `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com`) the HTTP request messages (i.e. the request headers) requests are the same as their `http:` equivalents  but the underlying HTTP connection is wrapped in a TLS (formerly SSL) connection.

In your case, you need to edit your nginx configuration to add another binding to your website that maps `http://<IP-address>` to your website, as well as `https://<IP-address>`. You need to check your web-application's code to ensure that it can handle requests using unexpected `Host:` headers - you can also configure nginx to modify the `Host` header for incoming requests to your usual header.

If you're using HTTPS then you'll need to add your IP address as a SAN (Subject Alternate Name) to your TLS certificate - which is generally a bad idea because IP addresses change and LetsEncrypt doesn't provide certificates for IP addresses anyway so this is moot.

For dev purposes and when you're running nginx locally (i.e. `http://localhost`) then you no-longer need a TLS certificate for `localhost` because since early 2020 Chromium-based browsers now recognize `http://localhost` as being a "secure" website even though it's over `http://` and not `https://`:

- https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6269417340010496
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=589141
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=691930

---

For an immediate workaround, you can use a browser-extension to override the `Host:` header when you're accessing a site by IP address.

e.g.:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-header-value-http/cbdibdfhahmknbkkojljfncpnhmacdek?hl=en
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en